# Yum: assume yes if install size < 1MB

Tags: fedora, software-installation, yum

I don't want to use `--assume-yes` option, but I'm fine with small installs (less than 1MB) to be processed without asking. Is there any way how to achieve that? I'm on Fedora 20.

Comment: I haven't used this before but you might look at [yum-plugin-filter-data](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch06s07.html) It looks like it can filter based on package sizes. If that works like I'm guessing it does, then you might be able to construct a cronjob with it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to filter by package size with `--assume-yes`, but you can query the packages by size with `repoquery`, and with some `awk` filtering, install just the files that have a download size with less than 1MB:

```
yum -y install `repoquery --pkgnarrow=updates -a --qf "%{name} %{size}" | awk '$2 < 1048576 {print $1}'`
```

What this command does: `repoquery` will get a query of packages of updates, create a 2 column list with package name and size, and with `awk` print only the name of packages that have less than `1048576` bytes(1MB). After that, you will pass this package list to yum ;)

Cheers.

Comment: I don't have much experience with `awk` or `repoquery` but this looks like it only filters per-package whereas I think when the OP says "install" they mean the total of all the packages to be installed. Seems like there would still be a way of doing it by totaling the second column and doing the comparison inside of `END`. Also, this approach doesn't ensure yum won't include a 1MB+ package as a dependency.

Comment: What @Joel says. Moreover, if a package is 70kB `foo.x86_64` with a 1G `foo-data.noarch`, then you need to detect this.

Comment: Well , this could happens with `libreoffice` for sure. Small packages with gigantic `-data` package dependencies. I´ll play with repoquery and dependency checking to query individual sets of packages and its dependencies. It will be some kind of "dependency hell" situation.